# Cannot load tag html in email codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-email

I have new problem in my website project

when I click validate for send email to email user

tag html cannot load in inbox

example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<h2>selamat datang Cumed Karlam di <a
href="http://www.cam-corp.com/">cam-corp</a></h2>
<br />
terima kasih atas partisipasi di <a
href='http://www.cam-corp.com/'>cam-corp</a>. 
anda telah bergabung menjadi operator di <a
href='http://www.cam-corp.com/'>cam-corp</a> dengan kata lain anda telah
menjadi reseller. 
semoga keberadaan anda di <a href='http://www.cam-corp.com/'>cam-corp</a>
dapat membantu <a href='http://www.cam-corp.com/'>cam-corp</a> menjadi
website jual beli yang terpercaya.
<br />
<br />
<br />
di bawah ini adalah username dan password anda di <a
href='http://www.cam-corp.com/'>cam-corp</a>.
<br />
-------------------------------------------------------
<br />
    username : ahmad7<br />
password : 4<br />
merk : Ahmad-ban<br />
-------------------------------------------------------
<br/>
<br />
<br />
</body>
</html>
```

can you help me ? thanks :)

Comment: I just wanted to say it is not a good practice to send password via email.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather unclear.

If you mean that the HTML code is not being parsed by a users mail client you need to specify a content type header like so:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
```